# Duplicate sybmol [SOAPEngine-iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

what is the problem here, it builds with real iphone device but when I want to build/run it with iPhone Simulator it show like this

```
duplicate symbol _DictionaryForNode in:
    /Users/**/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**-gfeynokufbufhkgjzjzwlijxekpb/Build/Intermediates/**.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/**.build/Objects-normal/i386/XPathQuery.o
    /Users/**/Downloads/SOAPEngine-master/SOAPEngine64.framework/SOAPEngine64(SOAPXPathQuery.o)
duplicate symbol _PerformXPathQuery in:
    /Users/**/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**-gfeynokufbufhkgjzjzwlijxekpb/Build/Intermediates/**.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/**.build/Objects-normal/i386/XPathQuery.o
    /Users/**/Downloads/SOAPEngine-master/SOAPEngine64.framework/SOAPEngine64(SOAPXPathQuery.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

FYI: there is no .m import or duplicate files in Build Phase

Comment: Have you tried deleting the derived data then cleaning the project and build it again ?

Comment: @SharonNathaniel Hmm really I didn't delete the derived data, lets me try thanks

Comment: what void architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Select the target and check out Build Phases. Make sure the same file isn't listed more than once.

Comment: Sure there is no duplicated files

Answer (score 0):

if you have XPathQuery.h/m in your project, in SOAPEngine it is already integrated, you need to remove only XPathQuery.m from your project, leave only XPathQuery.h, in the next version of SOAPEngine we'll fix this problem, please open an issue on GitHub for it.